# latex algorithm displaying problems: lines are overlapped

Tags: pdftex, algorithms, algorithmic

[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178090/latex-algorithm-are-displayed-with-overlapped-lines-of-code)
I am using `algorithm` package (built with `pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode` under `TexStudio`) to draw my algorithm. It works well on a template, but when I switch to another template, it is presented with lines overlapped as below.

[image]

The main tex file code is described below, please download the template source from [mdpi.com](http://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex):

```
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex,10pt,a4paper]{Definitions/mdpi} 

\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\firstpage{1} 
\makeatletter 
\setcounter{page}{\@firstpage} 
\makeatother
\pubvolume{xx}
\issuenum{1}
\articlenumber{1}
\pubyear{2018}
\copyrightyear{2018}
\externaleditor{Academic Editor: name}
\history{Received: date; Accepted: date; Published: date}
\Title{Title}
% Author Orchid ID: enter ID or remove command
\newcommand{\orcidauthorA}{0000-0000-000-000X} % Add \orcidA{} behind the author's name
%\newcommand{\orcidauthorB}{0000-0000-000-000X} % Add \orcidB{} behind the author's name

% Authors, for the paper (add full first names)
\Author{Firstname Lastname $^{1,\dagger,\ddagger}$\orcidA{}, Firstname Lastname $^{1,\ddagger}$ and Firstname Lastname $^{2,}$*}

% Authors, for metadata in PDF
\AuthorNames{Firstname Lastname, Firstname Lastname and Firstname Lastname}

% Affiliations / Addresses (Add [1] after \address if there is only one affiliation.)
\address{%
    $^{1}$ \quad Affiliation 1; e-mail@e-mail.com\\
    $^{2}$ \quad Affiliation 2; e-mail@e-mail.com}
\corres{Correspondence: e-mail@e-mail.com; Tel.: +x-xxx-xxx-xxxx}
\firstnote{Current address: Affiliation 3} 
\secondnote{These authors contributed equally to this work.}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
    \caption{algorithm caption} 
    \hspace*{0.02in} {Input:} 
    input parameters A, B, C\\
    \hspace*{0.02in} {Output:} 
    output result
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State some description 
        \For{condition} 
        \State ...
        \If{condition} 
        \State ...
        \Else
        \State ...
        \EndIf
        \EndFor
        \While{condition} 
        \State ...
        \EndWhile
        \State \Return result
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I have set up an git project on [github](https://github.com/qorost/latex-demo-algorithm.git), please feel free to clone it and try compiling it with `pdflatex`,

`git clone https://github.com/qorost/latex-demo-algorithm.git`

Any suggestions to increase the space between lines? any reply are appreciated!

Comment: Please make a small example document and add it inline to your question. this question and its answers are archived forever and will not make sense unless you also keep that github project unchanged forever.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just updated this question with my demo tex code as well as a link to download the template files. The styling files are too big and it is beyond my ability to make it inline.

Comment: better thanks (a MWE would be better still, but this will do:-) incidentally `\bf` isn't supposed to be used in latex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the suggestions. updated with `\bf` removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It's some strange interaction with `setspace` package and the other settings used. I didn't trace everything but you can reset the baselineskip so it isn't so cramped:

```
\section{Hello}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\setlength\baselineskip{13.5pt}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works. Actually, I also get a reply from MDPI editor, they shared a similar answer.

Comment: +1 I am also using the MDPI template and I am encountering the same problem. This got me through.

Comment: Looking at your answer picture it is still cramped (line 7-9)? I am just testing mdpi overleaf template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/mdpi-article-template/fvjngfxymnbr and your solution improves the situation but clearly does not solve the problem. Any other comments would be really valuable as when the algorithm is bigger the situation is even worse

Comment: As a fast fix I ended up adding small \spacing of 1.2 as in here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440499/algorithm-overlapping-code-lines-and-misplaced-final-horizontal-line and then manually fixing problematic lines with \vskip https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481757/algorithmicx-more-space-between-lines