# algorithmicx: More space between lines

Tags: algorithmicx, algpseudocode

My `algorithmicx` (more concretely: `algpseudocode`) lines contain quite a lot of sub-/superscripts, which makes them look quite "squeezed" onto each other.

How can I have them spaced a little apart without adding it manually after every line?

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4,parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

have:
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State do()
\State some()
\State stuff()
\end{algorithmic}

want:
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State do()\vskip 3pt
\State some() \vskip 3pt
\State stuff()
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

I already found out that when I prepend stuff to `\ALG@step`, it gets prepended to the line, but when I use `\vskip` or `\vspace` there, I get errors like  *missing } inserted* which I don't understand…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use `\onehalfspacing` from `setspace` package in the `algorithmic` environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4,parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}

have:
\begin{algorithmic}[1]\onehalfspacing
\State do()
\State some()
\State stuff()
\end{algorithmic}

want:
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State do()\vskip 3pt
\State some() \vskip 3pt
\State stuff()
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was easy, thank you :) I had inbetween made some hackery using a 0pt-width \rule to force a minimum height but this is way better